# bokeh server on_change from selected glyph not working

Tags: python, bokeh

I'm trying to use Bokeh's (server) `on_change` method to trigger an action when a glyph is selected (either with `tap` or `lasso_select`), but I can't even get it working for even a simple `print` statement.  Here is a minimal example that shows the problem.

```
from bokeh import plotting as bplt
from bokeh import layouts as blayouts
from bokeh import models as bmodels
from bokeh import io as bio

fig = bplt.figure(tools="lasso_select, tap")

source = bmodels.ColumnDataSource(dict(x=[1,0], y=[0,1]))

r = fig.circle('x', 'y', source=source, size=20)

def handler(attr, old, new):
    print('Hello')


source.on_change('selected', handler)

bio.curdoc().add_root(blayouts.layout([[fig]]))
```

Comment: Your example correctly prints "hello" when a circle is clicked or selected with the lasso. The print output is in the terminal.

Comment: Very strange.  Not in my terminal.  What browser are you running?

Comment: It works on firefox, chrome, and edge. I still use bokeh 0.12.10

Comment: Yes, must be a version issue.  I was on 1.0.x, downgraded to 0.13 and it works.  Will file and issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been changed in Bokeh 1.0.0. This is also shown in the [migration guide](https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/releases.html#migration-guide). It should work if you use this line of code:

```
source.selected.on_change('indices', callback)
```